# Is it possible to have sub-totals with an ExpandalbeListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I'm busy building an Activity that has the ExpandableListView. I'm mostly doing research at this point on how to do it etc.

The thing is with my list is there is cost field which displays the amount the item is worth. Each item is associated with a category, so that's why I have the expandablelistview.

Is it all possible to have the last row in the group be a totals record? Or have the total in the group header? If possible, are there any examples I can work from?

If this isn't possible, are there any other kind of widgets, views that can provide that kind of functionality?

Thanks

EDIT: As an example of what I mean, please see below

```
---Category - Cats ---- >
Cat 1         $10
Cat 2         $10
Cat 3         $10
Total         $30
---Category - Dogs ---- >
Dog 1         $10
Dog 2         $10
Dog 3         $10
Total         $30
---Category - Etc ---- >
Etc 1         $10
Etc 2         $10
Etc 3         $10
Total         $30
-------------------------------------
Grand Total: $90


Another option is to have it display like this

---Category - Cats - Total $30---- >
Cat 1         $10
Cat 2         $10
Cat 3         $10
---Category - Dogs - Total $30 ---- >
Dog 1         $10
Dog 2         $10
Dog 3         $10
---Category - Etc - Total $30 ---- >
Etc 1         $10
Etc 2         $10
Etc 3         $10
-------------------------------------
Grand Total: $90
```

Just keep in mind that the categories are all expandable as the lists will be much longer.

Answer (score 2):

Richard , an ExpandableListView is similar to a ListView So you can always use [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) or [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)) in a ExpandableListView

> Is it all possible to have the last
> row in the group be a totals record?

Richard , you can always update the headerView(or the footerView) as per the user's purchases to make the total.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for posting. I'll investigate those methods and update this post. I have the suspicion those methods should send me in the right direction.